# PHPExcel: Make gender column accept only "M" or "F"

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my project I am using `PHPExcel` for export and import records. I have tried `locking of sheets`, `locking of entire excel`, `unlocking certain fields only`, etc. And everything is work fine.

Now I need to limit a column for certain values only like

**If there is a `gender` column, then the column should allow to enter the values "M" and "F" only.**

Is there any way to do so using `PHPExcel`? I searched the documentation. But didn't get any answer.

Any help cold be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the ones who give negative votes: Please explain what is the reason? Or lead me to a track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use [Data Validation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) though you apply this to cells rather than to a column.

Examples [15datavalidation.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/15datavalidation.php) and [39dropdown.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/39dropdown.php) show some ways in which it can be used